# React input type="number" for floats

Tags: reactjs, floating-point, html-input

I want to have an input field of **type="number"**. (So that on mobile phones the numeric keyboard will appear). The problem is, that all my values are in cents: 1EUR = 100 Cents and I want to display a comma as a decimal separator (German format), so onChange will multiply the value with 100, and when the value is rendered, it is devided by 100. 
But when I type "5." after typing the next number the "." will get lost. The same happens with a ",".

I couldn't find any component already implemented that does this by using input type="number" instead of type="text".
So does anyone know such a library or a way to implement it, that does not include having two inputs, one for Cents and one for Euros?

Answer (score 0):

I think the number input type can handle the German comma system. So there might not be a need to manually change a 2,5 input into a 2.5.
If you use this changeHandler on a number input

```
const changeHandler = e => {
    const val = e.target.value
    console.log(2 * val)
    setNumber(val)
  }
```

the `val` variable will be a usual float while you see a comma in the input.